# Display the stored procedure on a form on button click

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I would like to display the selected stored procedure information not executing or some other kind. I will have my list of stored procedures displayed on the form where the user can select the required and if click on Generate button i would like to display the text of that stored procedure as it is on the web form

Sample Image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer just used this

```
    exec sp_helptext @storproc = 'stored_procedure_name'
```

Comment: Make sure your code handles procedures encrypted with `WITH ENCRYPTION`.